# Return no files from ftp gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to get all the files from a ftp directory. My configuration:

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="ftp.aaaaaa.bb"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="username" value="XXXXXXX"/>
    <property name="password" value="YYYYYYY"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="inbound"/>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inbound" expression="'GB2AV'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inbound"
    command="ls"
    command-options="-1"
    filename-pattern="*"
    remote-file-separator="\"
    expression="payload"
    reply-channel="outbound">
</int-ftp:outbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="outbound"/>

<int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter channel="outbound" append-newline="true"/>
```

It works great against my own test server (Ubuntu / vsftp). Against the production server (unknown OS and ftp server) I'm not able to get the file names. Debug output:

```
2016-11-01 16:58:17.017 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'outbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=[], headers={file_remoteDirectory=GB2AV\, id=a1a43b85-f086-fd0a-cbbb-a29548578820, timestamp=1478015897017}]
2016-11-01 16:58:17.017 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=GB2AV, headers={id=e4e4e425-f25d-e4de-7cd8-8912ecd5151b, timestamp=1478015895998}]
2016-11-01 16:58:17.130 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015897130; nextExpiration=1478015897125; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:17.130 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015897130; nextExpiration=1478015897125; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:18.135 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015898134; nextExpiration=1478015898130; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:18.135 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015898134; nextExpiration=1478015898130; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:19.136 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015899136; nextExpiration=1478015899134; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:19.136 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015899136; nextExpiration=1478015899134; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:20.137 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015900137; nextExpiration=1478015900136; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:20.137 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015900137; nextExpiration=1478015900136; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:21.142 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015901142; nextExpiration=1478015901137; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:21.142 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015901142; nextExpiration=1478015901137; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:22.147 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015902146; nextExpiration=1478015902142; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:22.147 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015902146; nextExpiration=1478015902142; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:23.151 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015903151; nextExpiration=1478015903146; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:23.151 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015903151; nextExpiration=1478015903146; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:24.154 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015904154; nextExpiration=1478015904151; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:24.154 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015904154; nextExpiration=1478015904151; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:25.159 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015905159; nextExpiration=1478015905154; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:25.159 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015905159; nextExpiration=1478015905154; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:25.995 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=GB2AV, headers={id=ec5a8b67-1b8e-d675-ad3e-e0ee5f4f955d, timestamp=1478015905995}]
2016-11-01 16:58:25.995 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=GB2AV, headers={id=ec5a8b67-1b8e-d675-ad3e-e0ee5f4f955d, timestamp=1478015905995}]
2016-11-01 16:58:25.995 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.ftp.gateway.FtpOutboundGateway     : org.springframework.integration.ftp.gateway.FtpOutboundGateway#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=GB2AV, headers={id=ec5a8b67-1b8e-d675-ad3e-e0ee5f4f955d, timestamp=1478015905995}]
2016-11-01 16:58:26.032 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.f.s.DefaultFtpSessionFactory       : Connected to server [ftp.aaaaaaa.bb:21]
2016-11-01 16:58:26.159 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015906159; nextExpiration=1478015906159; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:26.159 DEBUG 3957 --- [-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=0; now=1478015906159; nextExpiration=1478015906159; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2016-11-01 16:58:26.828 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'outbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=[], headers={file_remoteDirectory=GB2AV\, id=08ff9eb6-31e2-a575-a3ef-91ad4616f5f0, timestamp=1478015906828}]
2016-11-01 16:58:26.828 DEBUG 3957 --- [ask-scheduler-3] i.s.CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler : org.springframework.integration.stream.CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=[], headers={file_remoteDirectory=GB2AV\, id=08ff9eb6-31e2-a575-a3ef-91ad4616f5f0, timestamp=1478015906828}]
```

When connecting to the ftp server manually I can change the directory with `cd GB2AV` and show all files in this directory with  `ls`. I also tried all kind of combinations of file separators etc. etc.

When working with `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` I have to use `.listNames()` which returns `String[]` instead of `.listFiles()` which returns an empty object in my case.

Is there anything I can do in the gateway configuration or does it sound like some missing feature support on the server side?

Comment: Try to use `FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE` for the `AbstractFtpSessionFactory.clientMode`

Comment: This does not help. I tried both before.